# Sliding window calculation using R

Tags: performance, r

I have the following function `count.ones` that takes in a data frame `data.l` in which the observations have been subdivided into bins defined by indices, a vector of consecutive indices `x`, and the length of the sliding window `width` over consecutive indices. The goal of this function is to slide over the indices and count the number of observations labeled as ones.

```
count.ones = function(x,data.l,width){
  labvec = data.l$lab
  indvec = data.l$index
  return(sapply(1:(length(x)-(width-1)),
                       function(j) sum(labvec[indvec%in%x[j:(j+(width-1))]])))
}
```

My data is as follows:

```
library(ks)
library(zoo)
library(plyr)
library(BBmisc)
library(ggplot2)
library(rje)

set.seed(1234)
n1 = n2 = 50000
X1 = rnorm.mixt(n=n1,mus=c(0.4,0.8),sigmas=c(0.04,0.04),props=c(0.97,0.03))
X2 = rnorm.mixt(n=n2,mus=c(0.4,0.8),sigmas=c(0.04,0.04),props=c(0.98,0.02))

n1 = length(X1)
n2 = length(X2)

#pooled observations - label X1's as 1 and X2's as 0
dat = data.frame(X=c(X1,X2),lab=c(rep(1,n1),rep(0,n2)))

N = n1+n2 

#number in each bin
n = N^(1/3)

dat$quant = with(dat, cut_number(dat$X, n = round(N/n)))

#number of bins
M = length(levels(dat$quant))
dat$index = factor(dat$quant, levels = levels(dat$quant), 
                   labels = 1:length(levels(dat$quant)))
```

Example function call:

```
indx.contig = seq(M)
count.ones(x=indx.contig,data.l=dat,width=1) #can vary width for any integer >= 1
```

This function seems to be slower than expected as it's only performing the simple task of counting the number of 1's in each sliding window. This would become problematic as `n1` and `n2` increase into the millions (which is ultimately what I want to use). Is there a way to speed this up? I initially looked into `rollapply` in the `zoo` package, but it is not as flexible as my code.

It is important for me to look at *consecutive* indices. If, for example, I had:

```
indx.vec = c(1:10,14:20)
```

I would first create a list with two elements: one containing `1:10` and the other containing `14:20`. I would then run `count.ones` on each of the elements using `sapply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is inefficient because each iteration within the `sapply` has to search through the 100k rows of data to find the relevant ones. Without changing your code at all, you could get a significant speed improvement by first pre-aggregating your input data:

```
dat <- aggregate(lab ~ index, data = dat, FUN = sum)
```

This way, each iteration will only have to search through $M = 2154$ rows instead of the 100k. But it is not fixing everything and I prefer rewriting your code with your more general goal in mind, where

```
indx.vec <- c(1:10, 14:20)
```

First, aggregate your data using `tapply`:

```
agg.lab <- with(dat, tapply(lab, list(index), FUN = sum))
length(agg.lab)
# [1] 2154
head(agg.lab)
#  1  2  3  4  5  6 
# 25 23 26 21 22 21
```

It returns a vector containing `sum(lab)` for each distinct value of `index`. In the event that the data has no value for a given index, you could overwrite the output-ed `NA` with a `0` so as to not affect the upcoming roll sums:

```
agg.lab[is.na(agg.lab)] <- 0
```

Next, we subset by only keeping the indices in `indx.vec`

```
agg.lab   <- agg.lab[indx.vec]
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
# 25 23 26 21 22 21 19 21 24 28 21 18 24 22 23 21 20
```

Next, we map each value of `indx.vec` to the "group number" it belongs to (here, `1:14` belong to group #1 then `14:20` belong to group #2):

```
indx.grp  <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(indx.vec) != 1))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Using this vector of group indices, we break `agg.lab` into a list of vectors, one for each group number:

```
agg.split <- split(agg.lab, indx.grp)
# $`1`
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
# 25 23 26 21 22 21 19 21 24 28 
# 
# $`2`
# 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
# 21 18 24 22 23 21 20
```

Finally, we rollsum within each vector (where I used `width = 4` for illustration)

```
out <- lapply(agg.split, zoo::rollsum, k = width)
# $`1`
#  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
# 95 92 90 83 83 85 92 
# 
# $`2`
# 15 16 17 18 
# 85 87 90 86
```

With `indx.vec <- 1:M`, this code runs in 0.015 seconds on my machine, versus 12+ seconds for your `count.ones`. It also scales pretty well as it 
takes less than 0.4 sec for `n1 = n2 = 1e6`.